# VSCode C++ autocomplete icon missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

As shown in the image below, when I include the library header like iostream, there is no icon before the file name, while the C header file is normall. How to solve this problem?

[image: C++ icon missing]

Comment: That is not a problem. Just caused that C headers have a `.h` extension recognised in Windows as header files. Standard C++ headers don't have a header (for a reason I don't understand), and therefore, Windows and VSCode don't associate files without an extension to any type.

Comment: Thank you for reply. If similar issue happens to other users then it will be OK.